# Check table row based on value of input search SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

I have a table (multiselect mode) with a search field. Is there a way that when I search, the value of the search result will automatically check the corresponding row in the table. Initially I though I could just search and then if the result length is 1, do a getItems() on the table and setSelected = true on the first row. The row gets selected, but when I exit the searching, it the row get deselected.

```
        var oSerialTable = new sap.m.Table({
            mode: sap.m.ListMode.MultiSelect,
            columns: [
                ...
            ],
            items : {
                    path : "/results",
                    template: new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
                        cells: [
                        new sap.m.Text({ text: "{Sernr}" }),
                        new sap.m.Text({ text: "{Equnr}" }),
                        new sap.m.Text({ text: "{Lbbsa}" })
                        ]
                      })
            },
            select : function(evt){

            },
            updateFinished: function(){
                var aItems = oTable.getItems(); 
                console.log(aItems);
                if (aItems.length == 1){
                console.log(aItems[0]);
                aItems[0].setSelected(true)
                }

            }
        });

        oSerialTable.setModel(ocheckSerialBatchJsonModel);


        var oSerialTableSearch = new sap.m.SearchField({

            search: function(oEvent){

            var filterValue = oEvent.getSource().getValue();
            var aFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter("Sernr", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, filterValue);
            var oItemTemplate = new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
                cells: [
                    new sap.m.Text({ text: "{Sernr}" }),
                        new sap.m.Text({ text: "{Equnr}" }),
                        new sap.m.Text({ text: "{Lbbsa}" })


                ]
            });

                oSerialTableSearch.bindItems({path:"/SerialSet", template:oItemTemplate, filters: [aFilter]});


            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gets much easier if you bind the [selected property](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.ListItemBase.html#getSelected) of the `ColumnListItem` to your model.
You can then perform the filtering and selection on your model data:

```js
    ...      
                 template: new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
                    cells: [
                    new sap.m.Text({ text: "{Sernr}" }),
                    new sap.m.Text({ text: "{Equnr}" }),
                    new sap.m.Text({ text: "{Lbbsa}" })
                    ],
                    selected: "{selected}" //Bind selection to model
                  })

    ...

    var oSerialTableSearch = new sap.m.SearchField({
       search: function(oEvent){
           var filterValue = oEvent.getSource().getValue();
           var array = ocheckSerialBatchJsonModel.getProperty("/results");
           array.forEach(function(item){
              //update selected state of each item
              item.selected = (item.Sernr == filterValue || item.Equnr == filterValue || item. Lbbsa === filterValue);
           });
           ocheckSerialBatchJsonModel.setProperty("/results",array); //Write back to Model to update bindings
        }
    });
```

Example with your code on [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/vaberofene/1/edit?html,js,output).

Comment: thank you for this example. It is easier if I do it that way. Question is there a way that when users search, the value of the previously selected remains? So if I search for 123, 123 will be selected and if I search again for 124, it will also get selected (123 is also selected). Do I have to do a post method to my odata for this one? This is what I was thinking.

Comment: You can expand the selection if you add change the code to `item.selected = (item.selected || item.Sernr == filterValue || ...)` so that already selected items will stay selected.

Comment: I see! Great! Thank you for the help!