# Searching for value enable edit and save value in the table SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

Hi I have implemented a table that automatically adds 1 to the quantity of the value searched. Here is the [jsbin.](https://jsbin.com/wimivup/2/edit?js,console,output) . Implemented the table using this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39689400/check-table-row-based-on-value-of-input-search-sapui5/39690981#39690981)

Is there a way that aside from adding 1 to the quantity, the table will behave like a normal search filter that binds the result of the search to the items.

Example:

```
SNR     QUA 
123     1 
124     0
```

If I search for 123 on the search filter, the result will bind to the items of the table and +1 will be added to the QUA of 123. Result will be

```
SEARCH: 123

SNR     QUA
123     2
```

If I click the "X" button in the search field, the table will display

```
SNR     QUA
123     2
124     0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a Filter when the filterValue is filled and filter the table by the binding "items".

```
 var oFilter;

 if(filterValue){
    oFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter("Sernr", "EQ", filterValue);
  }

 oSerialTable.getBinding("items").filter(oFilter, sap.ui.model.FilterType.Application);
```

Check the
[Jsbin](https://jsbin.com/bevevuqusu/edit?js,console,output) here.

Comment: So you just really need to bind it with a filter. and just bind without a filter when you're finish. Thank you Leonardo for this.